# Is this query returning a reference to a cursor?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, cursor

I have a doubt about how a function returns a reference to a cursor in PostgreSQL. I have the following query :

```
CREATE FUNCTION reffunc(refcursor) RETURNS refcursor AS '
BEGIN
    OPEN $1 FOR SELECT col FROM test;
    RETURN $1;
END;
' LANGUAGE plpgsql;

BEGIN;
SELECT reffunc('funccursor');
FETCH ALL IN funccursor;
COMMIT;
```

Does this function return a reference to a cursor ? If not, how can I modify it to return a reference to a cursor ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `refcursor` variable contains the name of a *cursor*, a data structure that holds the active query.

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html#PLPGSQL-CURSOR-USING).

So yes, it is a reference to a cursor.